# Easiest, most maintainable online DB solution?

Tags: database

I wish to create an online system to track some things (e.g., a database with children, where each child has 1 or more visits from doctors). I want the users to be able to enter data as well as search for it, especially from mobile devices. So, this is a custom mobile online DB app of modest but non-zero size.

What would you recommend using to create such a system, considering things like

- ease of initial development
- ease and low cost of hosting
- ease of maintenance (e.g., no need to manually update components over time because of security problems, etc.)

?

Answer (score 2):

from the superficial description this sounds like a trivial web application, the "easiest" path will be to use the tools that you already know well

[people are most likely just going to recommend the tools they like/use, which while 'easiest' for them may have no bearing on your results]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommed http://dabbledb.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd for [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) (server side code is written in Python, db is on the Google's infrastructure); I think it respects your requirements:

- ease of initial development: Python is the simplest language ever
- ease and low cost of hosting: cost is zero
- ease of maintenance: maintenance cost is zero. Security should be high, since we're talking of Google

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at [Viravis](http://www.viravis.com).