# Easiest way to implement an online order tracking database

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-app-engine

I've been asked by a client to make an online tracking system for work we do for them (we will be typesetting a high volume of books for this client). Basically, it would be a database showing the books we are currently working on, with information on what stage of the project we are at, and estimated completion dates. The only people with access to this system would be us and employees of the client company.

I've worked in MySQL and PHP before; should I just go with what I know? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326364/easiest-most-maintainable-online-db-solution/326388#326388) to a similar question suggests using Google Apps. I don't have any experience with Python, but happy to learn...

Comment: It may or may not be an issue, but right now on AppEngine you can only use SSL if you access your app by the https://appname.appspot.com url.  If you use a custom cname you will not be able to use SSL.  See issue 792: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're the only one using this therefore I see no reason to use Google Apps. I'm usually weary of people suggesting Google Apps, Amazon's s3, Microsoft Azure, etc. Also, you're going to be using a radically different data store. Unless you want an excuse to learn to do Google Apps and Python, I'd say go with MySQL+PHP and be done with it! In short, there aren't really any technical reasons for you to go with Google Apps here.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with what you know is always a good solution when dealing with delivering products to customers. No customer likes to be your guinea pig while you learn a new technology, although that's often how it's done. If you are comfortable with MySQL and PHP then stick with it if it satisfies your requirements, if it seems not to then look for libraries, frameworks and components written in PHP that might help you reach that goal. If you still have difficulties (unlikely given the scope of the project given) then ask questions here :) & search the web for solutions and patterns.

If all that fails and you can clearly solve your problem with another technology, then look at moving but make sure your customer is aware of how that's going to affect you timeframes.

When you've implemented this project and have some spare time, if there's a new direction you'd like to explore then use this project as your base and set to work without the stress of a deadline.

That's my 2p worth... good luck!

Answer (score 2):

When developing a CRUD application such as this, you may be required to reinvent the wheel a little if starting from scratch. Many parts of your project are not unique to the project. E.g authentication, database access, form manipulation etc.

If getting things done is important to you it may be important to give your project a kick start and stop you wasting too much time.

**Use a coding framework**

Frameworks often have a lot of functionality ready for use straight out of the box.
Options may include [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com).

**Hack a tried and tested application**

Open source projects are often quite easy to mould to your needs. Drupal and Joomla are CMS products which can be used in a wide variety of ways. If your book-tracking drupal module is any good, maybe you could go on to offer it as an open source plugin?

**Use a currently available app in a new way**

Your app seems to be tracking the status of items added to a database. How about using software designed for tracking other types of items. E.g. bug tracking software, project management to-do list software or customer relationship management software?

Comment: Actually, your last point there is a really good one.  Redmine in particular lets you edit workflows and roles very easily, so it'd be easy herd it into shape as a job tracker I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as everyone has already said, if you already know PHP, that's got to be awfully tempting.

But it sounds simple enough that something like Django might save you a lot of time: its built-in admin interface could be used for the "update" side of the job, so all you'd need to template up is the "read" side, which is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you too look at [Viravis](http://www.viravis.com).